# Accessing the same object from concurrent threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, object

Have two object instance that i should access from two concurrent thread, from the VCL thread and from a worker thread.

```
TSlave = class
  ...
public
  ...
  statusByte: byte;
  ...
end;

TMaster = class
private
  FSlaves: TList;
  FrBuffer: array of byte;  
  ...
public
  CMD_GET_SLAVE( aSlave: TSlave );
  ...
end;

procedure TMaster.CMD_GET_SLAVE( aSlave: TSlave );
begin
  ...
  rBuffer := udpsend(); //calling a function that sends udp packet and returns the answer
  aSlave.statusByte := rBuffer[2];
  ...
end;
```

I store the references of the slave objects in the 'Data' fields of VCL TTreeNodes - treenode.data (i store them also in a TMaster private list).

There are two 'option' for accessing the slave object (writing slave.statusByte) and the TMaster instance (as i access the slave object through a TMaster instance) >>

1. Clicking on the treenode. When this happens i send an UDP packet with calling master.CMD_GET_SLAVE, in this method i read the answer from FrBuffer and writing slave.statusByte.
2. There is a worker thread that is cyclically doing the same (calling master.CMD_GET_SLAVE). This case i dont get the slave instances from treenode.data, but from the master's TList object (FSlaves).

The question is, how to manage this correctly? Because there is a possible situation when the user clicks on the treenode and in the same time there could be an incoming access from the thread.

I dont touch any VCL control from the worker thread, 'just' accessing the same objects from two concurrent thread. Should i just do the same synchronization that im doing when synchronizing the main VCL thread (because of refreshing some visual VCL control)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have multiple threads that access access a shared object, and at least one thread modifies the object, then you usually need to use a lock (for instance `TCriticalSection` or `TMonitor`) to serialize access to the shared object. Some options for doing so:

1. Externally protect all access to the shared object with the lock.
2. Make the object self synchronizing using its own private lock. That is the internally synchronized option.
3. Option 2 is simpler for the caller, but forces all consumers of the class to pay the cost of synchronization. A an alternative is to make the object have no internal synchronization but then wrap a synchronization class around it that presents a thread-safe version.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular example, accessing the slaves across multiple threads is not a problem.  The real problem is `udpsend()`.  You are running the risk of having two threads sending requests at the same time and then reading each other's responses.  Depending on the nature of your UDP protocol, that may or may not cause problems.

If it does, you might need to move the UDP communications to its own dedicated thread.  When you need to send a request, you could put it in a thread-safe queue that the thread looks at, along with info about what to do with the response when it arrives (assign it to a slave, call a callback function, signal a waitable event, etc). The thread can pick up a queued request and send it.  When the response comes back, it can delegate it accordingly.  `CMD_GET_SLAVE()` would then block its calling thread waiting for that response to arrive. This would help avoid any overlaps.

Comment: Thank You. You are telling accessing the same objects/field are not a problem here. Thats because i dont make any calculations from the threads on 'statusByte', just writing it and so its 'atomic'?
About udpsend, well i was thinking just to make another instance of TIdUDPClient, but thats a waste of resources. The queue you mention, it would be nice to see something like that in practice.